# How to integrate ondrive with offce online using API...?

Tags: office365, onedrive

I was developed application of onedrive with API.But if i want to open DOC or XLS file in office365 (like actual onedrive file view) what i need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **share link** using the OneDrive REST API like below:

```
POST:https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/{itemId}/action.createLink
{
    "type":"view",
    "scope":"anonymous"
}
```

Then you can navigate to the web Url return by the request to view the Office document online.

Refer to [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/sharing_createLink.htm) for detail about creating a sharing link for an item in OneDrive.